Movie with massive fire alien thing destroys bridge and eats train
So I'm in Costa Rica and there was a movie on this afternoon in English with Spanish subtitles. I only saw a few minutes of it but basically what I saw was some military men loading a bomb on to a train in the forest at night and then the train stopped and in the distance they could see some fire. Then some men went ahead to check out the bridge ahead. While they were on the bridge, this massive alien thing comes up next to them and its all black with these lava like eyes. It breaks the bridge and the guys fall down into the lake below. The creature then somehow sets the train on fire and eats the train along with the bomb. 
Lol super random I know but theres literally hundreds of movies that meet the description of "fire alien breaks bridge". If anyone knows it would be greatly appreciated as I would love to finish the movie.

Welcome to Movies & TV stackexchange Please add any details you know: Country of origin (or at least language), estimated year of release (or at least the year you saw it), actors you recognize (or even just what they look like), was it in theaters or only on TV, any other minor plot points. The more you can give us, the more likely we can help you.

That must be the latest Godzilla (2014):

Ford joins a team delivering the warheads by train. The female MUTO attacks the train and devours the warheads. The remaining warhead is airlifted to the city and is activated after the military fails to stop Godzilla at the Golden Gate Bridge.

Here is the scene on Youtube:




yes thats it! thank you!!!

You are welcome, please mark your question as answered.

This is the 2014 release of Godzilla.  I remember that scene well.  Great movie.  (And if you're a fan of Once Upon a Time, you'll recognize the small town.)
